# Difference between: .Font.FontStyle = "Bold" vs .Font.Bold = msoTrue

Tags: excel, vba

I am building charts through excel-vba. I am using one of the lines below to make my X-axis fonts in bold:

```
       Activechart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
       Activechart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

Both of these methods work but I am wondering what is the difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use FontStyle to set multiple font properties at once

`ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"`

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font

    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True

End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that too but I was wondering if there is any other difference.

Comment: The property doesn't seem to be too versatile.  I think Excel is just mimicking the Web API's Font object.

Answer (score 1):

The Font.FontStyle = "Bold" didn't well as the .Font.Bold  ...it didn't work because it takes, for example, the word "Bold", from the region settings of excel, in my case takes the word "Εντονα", which is the Bold in Greek.
Now if you want to compare for example:

`if the selection.Font.fontstyle="Bold" then...`

In an excel with Greek regional settings, you will take wrong results.

It is safe to use.Font.Bold = True to avoid the above.

Comment: this looks like a very valid reason to use .Font.Bold = True.
Thanks!